# When creating a database using an ERD, what do the entities and relationships become (in database terms)?

Tags: tools, learning

MIS student, here. Learning about ERDs (entity relationship diagrams). ERDs are supposedly used for the purpose of later constructing a database. My question is this:

- What will an entity (and, likewise, an entity's attributes) become upon implementing the database? For instance, will entities turn into rows and attributes into columns?
- In fact, now that I consider it, I'd like to know how one implements associative entities from ERD to database form as well. Is there a difference between what a regular entity and an associative entity represent in terms of database terminology?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When implementing an ERD as physical database the following mappings apply:

- An entity becomes a table (set of rows)
- A relationship becomes a foreign key.
- Associative (many to many) relationships become a table with a foreign key to each associated table.

Generally the ERD shoud be in at least third normal form.

A few notes about relationships:

- The (zero or) one side of the relationship is implemented as the  primary key of the table.
- The many side of the relationship is usually implemented with a foreign key index.
- If the site opposite the many side range is zero to one, the foreign keys column(s) are nullable.
- If the side opposite the many side range is one to one, the foreign key columns are not nullable.
- If the side opposite the many side range is also zero or one to many, then a relationship table must be implemented.

Many ERD tools can be used to create the tables and indexes; or the DDL (Data Definition Language) to do so.  They may also be able to create an ERD from a database.  The best tools can update an existing database to match a modified ERD, or generate the DDL to modify the database.

Comment: I don't think the nullable vs. non-nullable part is correct.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ  Seems correct to me. If the business rules allow orphans, child records not assigned to a parent, then the foreign key value in that child table will be a NULL. Alternatively, you can create a specific parent row whose ID you assign as the foreign key on all the otherwise would-be-orphans. If your business rules forbid orphans, such as every invoice-line-item child must be assigned to an invoice parent, then the foreign key on invoice-line-item should be defined as NOT NULL.

Comment: But that is irrelevant to whether the relationship is 1 to 0-to-many or 1 to 1-to-many.